# How to create an algorithm with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new on this platform and I want to know if I can create an algorithm using your help and advises.

I received this project where I need to find the new price and the last price for different agreements, taking into consideration the availability of the these contracts together with the quantity sold (which can be scaled) since the version of SAP does not have any audit history of user actions.

I managed to filter the pairs of two contracts but this represents only 20% of this project. Now I would like to create an algorithm that can filter the agreements renewed with different quantities sold at different prices, on the same/different time period. The business scenario for this part is to look for the 2 closest numbers for all cases when there are 2 different arrays or same array, for different types of date intervals. The tools that I have to work with are SQL Server Management Studio and Alteryx designer. Do you think you can help me?

An example of the table I have to work with is the below (but there are thousands of keys):

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific because the format of your question is not suitable for Stack Overflow. Stack gives answers to well specified, code-based questions

Comment: If you could provide some sample data DDL, an expected output and what you are already tried would be helpful

Comment: Hello, I do not have a specific code to ask for help because I have to write it in order to create an algorithm that works based on the business requirements. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Dohsan, the expected output is the Column "New Agreement". This is how the algorithm should treat the keys.

Comment: So you want to select values for the NEW_AGREEMENT column. You are showing the following values: 'do not consider', 'LAST' , 'NEW', 'LAST 1', 'NEW 1', 'overlapping', 'no renwal yet' and null. Are these all? Is null one of the target values or shall there remain no rows with NEW_AGREEMENT null? Anyway, for each value write down by what rule you want to set the value. For instance: When is a row declared 'NEW'? What must be looked at and compared to get this value? Do this for all values.

Comment: @LazaroiuDaniel  Most people will not be able to see any of the data on your screenshot. You need to provide the data in its columns/rows so people are able to then use to help answer your question. Similarly you need to show from that input what the output would be (How many rows/columns are expected)

Comment: The most difficult part is that all of the above from New Agreement represents corner cases. The principle described there is how the business take the decisions. What I wanted to show to all of you is somehow about the "Way they make the decision".

Comment: SELECT 
 row_number() over (partition by [Key2],[ValidFrom],[ValidTo] order by [ValidFrom] asc) as X
,Count ([ScaleQuantity]) OVER(PARTITION BY  [Key2],[ValidFrom],[ValidTo] order by [ValidFrom] asc) AS ScaleN
,Count ([Price]) OVER(PARTITION BY  [Key2],[ValidFrom],[ValidTo] order by [ValidFrom] asc) AS PriceN
,[Key2] 
,[ValidFrom]
,[ValidTo]
,[TargetQuantity]
,[ScaleQuantity]
 ,[Price]
FROM    
[Test_Daniel_Lazaroiu].[dbo].[SPA_View_JUL]
group by 
 [Key2] 
,[ValidFrom]
,[ValidTo]
,[TargetQuantity]
,[ScaleQuantity]
,[Price]

Comment: This is the query I used so far to have a partition made by KEY (which represents the contracts) and time interval (ValidFrom and ValidTo). This is helping me to have a correct output (described in the picture) to easily identify how an overlapping/scale case looks like.

Comment: Now, from what I understood, I need to continue at least with the idea about how to compare the 2 most closest ScaleQuantity value (to get the price that corresponds to it) based on the same partition described.

Comment: I tried to use the standard_deviation since it calculates how far from average two or more numbers are. But it blocks me when there is only one distinct row, because in this case standard_deviation is 0.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will try to do it by myself to try to cover at leas 50% of this. And sorry for this business case so complex.

Comment: Once you've tried working on it, you can use this reference to improve your question so you can get the best help possible: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask